# Prove the polynomial $x^4+4 x^3+4 x^2-4 x+3$ is positive

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, sum-of-squares-method

Given the following polynomial
$$
x^4+4 x^3+4 x^2-4 x+3
$$
I know it is positive, because I looked at the graphics

[image]

and I found with the help of Mathematica that the following form
$$
(x + a)^2 (x + b)^2 + c^2(x + d)^2 + e^2
$$
can represent the polynomial with the following values for the constants
$$
\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2
   \left(x+\frac{5}{2}\right)^2+\frac{5}{2} \left(x+\frac{1}{5}\right)^2+\frac{107}{80}
$$

I suppose there are simpler ways to prove that the polynomial is positive, perhaps by using some inequalities.
Please, advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just another solution (similar to Albus Dumbledore's).

$$x^4+4x^3+4x^2-4x+3=x^2(x+2)^2-4x+3 = x^4+4x^3+(2x-1)^2 +2$$
For $x<0$ we have $-4x+3>0$ and therefore $x^2(x+2)^2-4x+3>0$.

For $x>0$ it follows from $x^3>0$ that $x^4+4x^3+(2x-1)^2 +2>0$.

Comment: I think this solution is the simplest, because only uses the square of a binomial

Answer (score 9):

Here's a slightly more motivated way to find a sum-of-squares representation.

We should want the first term to be the square of a quadratic with leading coefficient $1$, and to cancel out the $x^3$ term we need it to be $(x^2+2x+a)^2$ for some real $a$. This will leave us to show that
$$-2ax^2-(4a+4)x+(3-a^2)\geq 0;$$
the simplest case of this is to choose $a=-1$ (to remove the $x$ term entirely), which gives us that
$$x^4+4x^3+4x^2-4x+3=(x^2+2x-1)^2+2x^2+2>0.$$

Comment: Very clever! IMO this is the best answer: simple and effective

Comment: Can such proofs be constructed for arbitrary polynomials with real integer coefficients? Suppose I have a crazy polynomial (of even degree, obviously) in one variable $x$, with real (integer) coefficients. Can I determine with certainty whether its values are all $\ge 0$ and maybe even all $>0$, or not, in a finite calculation? (By Abel–Ruffini, there is no general closed formula for its zeros or extrema.)

Comment: (continuing) The degree of the polynomial is even, and WLOG, we can take the leading coefficient to be positive. Then I suppose it is obvious that the range is of the form $\left[ m,+\infty \right)$ for some unknown real number $m$ (the global minimum). I suppose, if $m\ne 0$, then that can be determined with certainty by a long but finite numerical calculation? But if we do not know if $m=0$, can we determine if $m=0$ in a finite calculation?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen If we're allowing any algorithm, it's not that hard to approximate the roots of the derivative of a polynomial with certainty, and so we can get arbitrarily good bounds on $m$ in finite time. If we're trying to determine if $m=0$, we need only to calculate $\gcd(f(x),f'(x))$ (which is a finite calculation) and determine whether it has any real roots, which I'd imagine is not hard (not 100% sure). If we do this first, we should be able to determine whether $m<0$, $m=0$, or $m>0$ in finite time.

Comment: (cont'd) This says nothing about finding a sum-of-squares proof of this result, for which I assume there's some research (since it's known that a positive polynomial is the sum of two squares). I'd *guess* that the strategy given in my answer works at least for degree $4$, although it's not immediately clear to me what an extension to higher degrees would look like. If you try to decrease the degree by a factor of $1/2$ each time, the polynomial $x^6+2x^3+2x^2$ causes problems (since you try to subtract $(x^3+1)^2$ and lose equality at $x=0$), and only decreasing degree by $2$ each time ...

Comment: ... leaves you with many variables to optimize and likely a much harder problem.

Comment: But if we could determine whether the polynomial $\gcd(f(x),f'(x))$ has any real roots, why can we not instead determine directly if $f(x)$ has any real roots? I tried to google, and it seems it can always be determined if a real polynomial (in one variable) has a real root or not: [Wikipedia: Sturm's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem) (related to your suggestion with $f'(x)$); [MathOverflow: Criteria to determine whether a real-coefficient polynomial has real root?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20946/)

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Ah yes, that does work just fine. Maybe I should stop doing math too late at night ...

Answer (score 8):

if $x\ge 0$ by AM-GM $$x^4+3=x^4+1+1+1\ge 4x$$  and the inequality $$\color{blue}{x^4+3-4x}+4x^3+4x^2>0$$ is obvious as equality of am-gm and $x=0$ is simultaneously is not achieved.

If $x\le 0$ then replace $x$ by $-t $ and we have to prove $$t^4-4t^3+4t^2+4t+3>0$$which is true as $$t^4+4t^2\ge 4t^3$$ by AM-GM and as  $t\ge 0$ and the rest of terms are postive (note :again equality of both AM-GM and t=0 is not achieved)

Answer (score 1):

Let the polynomial be denoted by $f(x)$.
$f'(x)=4(x^3+3x^2+2x-1)$ has only one real root $\approx 0.3247$. At that point $f''(x)=4(3x^2+6x+2)>0$. Thus $f(x)$ has minimum value at $\approx 0.3247$ and $f(0.3247)\approx 2.271$.

$\therefore f(x)>0 \;\forall x\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: How do you find the root of $f'$? this is not immediate